# My Tier 2 is getting transferred to another company. Can I work in the interim?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, australian-citizens

I've left my previous sponsor, and I have my CoS and an appointment with UK Visas & Immigration in a few days. In the interim, I've been told I can legally do up to 16 hours of work per week. I'm unable to find supporting documentation. Does anyone know where this information is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot work until you have your visa. You were wise to research this.